# How to fail a collection when its fixture throws an Exception?

Tags: c#, xunit

I'm currently writing a suite of integration tests for a mature ASP.NET application.
As part of the application's supporting services, it uses an Azure blob storage container which I need to make sure is accessible and existing prior to running the tests. I want to add what effectively amounts to a check that the configured Azure blob container for the application (be it on the local emulator or Azure itself when running in CI) is up and ready to handle the requests made by the test suite. A large amount of the tests will straight up fail if the backend is inaccessible and they take several minutes to fail as the Azure library waits through several timeouts.

When throwing or asserting in a collection fixture, it doesn't seem to actually prevent any test in the collection from running nor does the fixture exception appear in the resulting logs.

Is there a way to prevent tests from running if any of their associated fixtures throw during instantiation?

---

My current code is as follows:

The fixture

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IO;
using Xunit;

namespace product.test.integration
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This fixture ensures the configured azure blob container used by the FileStorage system is accessible.
    /// A concern mostly in local environments where the Azurite emulator may not be running, but also can alert to a misconfigured testing environment.
    /// </summary>
    public class FileStorageFixture
    {
        public FileStorageFixture()
        {
            //get the configuration
            string appdataLocation = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "testappsettings.json");
            string appdataContent = File.ReadAllText(appdataLocation);
            var json = JObject.Parse(appdataContent);
            string connectionString = json["Settings"]["FileStorage"]["AzureStorageKey"].Value<string>();
            string containerName = json["Settings"]["FileStorage"]["ContainerName"].Value<string>();
            //check if the container exists
            var container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
            try
            {
                Assert.True(container.Exists()); //this line will throw if a timeout occurs
            } catch
            {
                throw new System.Exception("Configured FileStorage backend is not accessible!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The base test class (IntegrationTest) which all tests extend, and the collection that contains them:

```
//...
    [CollectionDefinition("Integration Tests", DisableParallelization = true)]
    public class IntegrationTestCollection :
        //...
        ICollectionFixture<FileStorageFixture> { }

    [Collection("Integration Tests")]
    public abstract class IntegrationTest : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<product.api.Startup>>
    {
//...
```

Comment: Could you detect this condition in the constructor of `IntegrationTest` and fail there?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins My hope was to do it in a collection fixture so that it doesn't have to be run more than once. If the connection check fails the entire collection is going to fail so why would I run any of the tests within if I know they are going to fail. It's certainly possible to do it in the constructor, but I'm guessing it would still wait through the Azure library's 6 timeouts before failing, but for each test class this time

Comment: I would assume that `IntegrationTest` gets a reference to the `FileStorageFixture` in its constructor. If you added a flag `public bool initOK {get; private set;}` to the fixture and set it to `false` if there is a problem, you could check the flag in the constructor of  `IntegrationTest` or its derived classes and fail there immediately with `Assert.True(fixture.initOK, "No fixture available");`

Comment: You could also try doing `Environment.FailFast("No connection");` in the fixture. I had some cases where the tests were throwing memory access exceptions, which as "corrupted state exceptions" are not caught and brought the process down; in this case the remaining tests were simply skipped, maybe `FailFast` would do the same thing. But it would also cause tests not in the collection not to run either.

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins Both of your suggestions are great! I ended up going with the flag method. If you're interested in turning your comments into an answer I'd be glad to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you desire is to have the fixture set a flag if its initialization was not successful and query the flag in the constructor of your base test class.

In `FileStorageFixture` add the flag as a property

```
    public bool initOK { get; private set; } = false;
```

and set the property depending on whether the initialization was successful

```
     try
     {
        Assert.True(container.Exists()); //this line will throw if a timeout occurs
        initOK = true;
     } 
     catch
     {
        initOK = false;
     }
```

It would be even more reliable if you included the rest of the code in the `FileStorageFixture` constructor inside the `try`, since an exception anywhere there would also bring your tests down.

I assume the reference to the fixture is being provided as a parameter to the constructor of `IntegrationTest`, so you should throw an exception there if the fixture wasn't initialized properly:

```
    public IntegrationTest(FileStorageFixture fixture) 
    {
        Assert.True(fixture.initOK, "Configured FileStorage backend is not accessible!");

        // ... and do the rest of the constructor stuff
    }
```

Without the `IntegrationTest` object, none of its tests will run.